# I want to reshape the following wide data frame as into long

Tags: r, reshape

Here is my wide data

```
 Year Period       Day1       Day2       Day3       Day4       Day5       Day6       Day7
1 1995      1 1995-01-02 1995-01-03 1995-01-04 1995-01-05 1995-01-06 1995-01-07 1995-01-08
2 1995      2 1995-01-09 1995-01-10 1995-01-11 1995-01-12 1995-01-13 1995-01-14 1995-01-15
3 1995      3 1995-01-16 1995-01-17 1995-01-18 1995-01-19 1995-01-20 1995-01-21 1995-01-22
4 1995      4 1995-01-23 1995-01-24 1995-01-25 1995-01-26 1995-01-27 1995-01-28 1995-01-29
5 1995      5 1995-01-30 1995-01-31 1995-02-01 1995-02-02 1995-02-03 1995-02-04 1995-02-05
6 1995      6 1995-02-06 1995-02-07 1995-02-08 1995-02-09 1995-02-10 1995-02-11 1995-02-12
```

I want to reshape it into long as

```
Year    Period  Day
1995    1   1995-01-02
1995    1   1995-01-03
1995    1   1995-01-04
1995    1   1995-01-05
1995    1   1995-01-06
1995    1   1995-01-07
1995    1   1995-01-08
1995    2   1995-01-09
1995    2   1995-01-10
1995    2   1995-01-11
1995    2   1995-01-12
1995    2   1995-01-13
1995    2   1995-01-14
1995    2   1995-01-15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(reshape2)
 mDat <- melt(dat, id.var=c("Year", "Period"))[,-3]
 mDat1 <- mDat[order(mDat$Year, mDat$Period),]
 row.names(mDat1) <- 1:nrow(mDat1)
 head(mDat1)
 # Year Period      value
 #1 1995      1 1995-01-02
 #2 1995      1 1995-01-03
 #3 1995      1 1995-01-04
 #4 1995      1 1995-01-05
 #5 1995      1 1995-01-06
 #6 1995      1 1995-01-07
```

Or you can use `dplyr` with `tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

  dat%>% 
      gather(Var, Day, starts_with("Day")) %>% 
      select(-Var) %>% 
      arrange(Year, Period) %>%
      head()

  #Year Period        Day
  #1 1995      1 1995-01-02
  #2 1995      1 1995-01-03
  #3 1995      1 1995-01-04
  #4 1995      1 1995-01-05
  #5 1995      1 1995-01-06
  #6 1995      1 1995-01-07
```

Comment: seems the one liner is enough to work : gather(dat, days, value, -Year, -Period)

Comment: @KFB Yes, if there is no need to order.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reshape2` library and function `melt`. Here is an example. You can melt by ID variables:

```
library(reshape2)
data <- data.frame(year=rep("2013", 5), period=seq(1,5), day1=seq(2,6), day2=seq(3,7))
data <- melt(data, id.vars=c("year", "period"))
```

Or you can melt by measure variables:

```
data <- melt(data, measure.vars=c("day1", "day2"))
```

You just have to drop one unnecessary column

```
data <- data[,-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Using base R

```
reshape(d, varying = paste0("Day", 1:7), sep = "", direction = "long")
```

2) An alternative, using `tidyr`

```
gather(d, id, Day, Day1:Day7)
```